# Lexical error at line 0, column 0

Tags: javacc

In the grammar below, I am trying configure any line that starts with `'` as a single line comment and anything betweeen `/' Multiline Comment '/`. The single line comment works ok. But for some reason as soon as I press `/` or `'` or ';' or `<` or '>' I get the error below. I don't have above characters configured. Shouldn't they be considered default and skip parsing ?

**Error**

```
Lexical error at line 0, column 0.  Encountered: "\"" (34), after : ""
Lexical error at line 0, column 0.  Encountered: ">" (62), after : ""
Lexical error at line 0, column 0.  Encountered: "\n" (10), after : "-"
```

I have only included part of the code below for conciseness. For full Lexer definition please visit the [link](http://pastie.org/7959994)

```
TOKEN :
{
  < WHITESPACE:
  " "
| "\t"
| "\n"
| "\r"
| "\f">
}

/* COMMENTS */

MORE :
{
  <"/'"> { input_stream.backup(1); } : IN_MULTI_LINE_COMMENT
}

<IN_MULTI_LINE_COMMENT>
TOKEN :
{
  <MULTI_LINE_COMMENT: "'/" > : DEFAULT
}

<IN_MULTI_LINE_COMMENT>
MORE :
{
  < ~[] >
}

TOKEN :
{
  <SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT: "'" (~["\n", "\r"])* ("\n" | "\r" | "\r\n")?>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce every aspect of your problem. You say there is an error "*as soon as*" you enter certain characters. Here is what I get.

- `/` There is no error unless the next character is not a `'`. If the next character is not `'`, there is an error.
- `'` I see no error. This is correctly treated as the start of comment
- `;` There is always an error. No token can start with `;`.
- `<` There only an error if the next characters are not `-` or `<-`.
- `>` There always is an error. No token can start with `>`

I'm not exactly sure why you would expect these not to be errors, since your lexer has no rules to cover these cases. Generally when there is no rule to match a prefix of the input and the input is not exhausted, there will be a `TokenMgrError` thrown.

If you want to eliminate all these `TokenMgrError`s, make a catch-all rule (as explained in the FAQ):

```
TOKEN: { <UNEXPECTED_CHARACTER: ~[] > }
```

*Make sure this is the very last rule in the .jj file.*  This rule says that, when no other rule applies, the next character is treated as an `UNEXPECTED_CHARACTER` token.  Of course this just boots the problem up to the parsing level.  If you really want the tokenizer to skip all characters that don't belong, just use the following rule *as the very last rule:*

```
SKIP : { < ~[] > }
```

For most languages, that would be an odd thing to do, which is why it is not the default.

Comment: One of the things I tried yesterday includes `TOKEN: { <OTHER: ~[] > }` which didn't work probably because of other reasons. I said `as soon as I enter` because I am developing this lexer to provide syntax higlighting in an IDE. I don't have plans to implement a parser yet, so if I just skip the characters that don't belong to the language, that should suffice. 

 I spent all day yesterday trying to fix this and was able to fix it this morning in one shot after seeing your answer. I suppose they call you a scientist for a reason :). Answers like these should be awarded 100 points atleast. THX.

Comment: Thanks.   You had the solution all along.  Good luck with the project.